# Calculate destination coordinate from a coordinate and heading information

Tags: iphone, location, coordinate, heading, bearing

If I Have information with one coordinate (lat, lon) and true heading degree in iPhone, how can I find a destination coordinate from this?

> ex) starting coordinate2D: 37.6009, 126.8647
>
> true heading: 271.4766227
>
> distance: 0.8m

destination coordinate?

P.s I think it's OK if it does not use formula about ellipse because it is short in comparison with the circumference of the earth.

But if considering ellipse formula do, that's better.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633850/calculate-new-coordinate-x-meters-and-y-degree-away-from-one-coordinate