# Android Google Maps get expanded boundary co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, bounds

I am using Google Maps v2 in my application. When the user pans or zooms on the screen I would like to get the map expanded (by x Km) bounding box.

Let's say the black rectangle in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCtkf.png represents the map view, I want to expand these boundaries by 50 Km from each side (the red rectangle) and get it's LatLng coordinates.

I already know how to get the boundary coordinates of the map (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14700745/926868)).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use The haversine formula.

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258078/latitude-longitude-and-meters).