# Calculate location by distance from other location

Tags: ios, core-location

I know there are tons of questions (and answers) on how to get the distance between two CLLocations. But I didn't find one single hint on how to do this the other way round.

Here's the concrete situation: I have one CLLocation, one distance (let's say 200 meters) and one direction. Now I need to know how to calculate the location that is 200 meters away (in a specified direction) from the first location. I don't know what could be the best format for the direction. Maybe the best would be in degrees (north = 0, east = 90, south = 180, west = 270).

In a nutshell, I need a method that could be defined like

```
-(CLLocation*)locationWithDistance:(int)meters inDirection:(int)degrees fromLocation:(CLLocation*)origin;
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There are also possibly tons of this question.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633850/calculate-new-coordinate-x-meters-and-y-degree-away-from-one-coordinate

Comment: Looks like I searched for the wrong keywords. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more accurate method use this formula in the link

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Please find the section "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point". Apply it in your code

Answer (score 0):

There is C code already written to do exactly that.  It is posted on [github here](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/Utils/UtilitiesGeo.c).  There is a degrees and radians version of the function in UtilitiesGeo.c/.h files.  It could have been written with an Objective-C style but I wanted it to be portable to any C based project.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Given a starting lat/lon point on earth, distance (in meters)
* and bearing, calculates destination coordinates lat2/lon2.
*
* all params in degrees
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void destCoordsInDegrees(double lat1, double lon1,
                         double distanceMeters, double bearing,
                         double* lat2, double* lon2);
```