# How to place a view next to an MKRoute in a MapKit app

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

I have an app that is using MapKit's `MKRoute`. I want to place a `UIView` on the route on the map, similar to how Apple annotates routes in Maps with an estimated travel time popover:

http://www.siprog2.com/pjx/fichiers/mkroute.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MKAnnotation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotation) to annotate a specific coordinate point on your route. Your `MKMapView`'s delegate will then be asked to return an [`MKAnnotationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview) if your annotation is in the currently visible area of the map.

Apple has [sample code for adding custom annotation views to a map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data) (it's not using a route, but all you need to change is annotate a point on your route).

Comment: Indeed, i was looking for in a bad direction, and finaly find a previous post on this subject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995787/annotation-along-route-in-mapkit