# MKMapview fix user at bottom of map

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, coordinates, mkmapcamera

I'm creating a navigation app and want the map to show the users location at the bottom of the map, like in Maps app when routing/navigating. However you can only determine which coordinate to focus on by using the centre coordinate.

[image: 2D offset view]

Therefore I need to calculate an offset distance and bearing and calculate a coordinate that this represents the central coordinate that will allow the displaying of the users location at the bottom of the map.

This is all complicated by the 3D view where the camera pitch and altitude affects the relationship of distance between the offset coordinate and the users location.

[image: 3D view]

Is there an easier way to do this or does someone know how to calculate this?

Thanks (a lot!)

D

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509112/set-current-location-icon-lower-side-in-mkmapview