# Change Camera Zoom based on Radius Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on an app that displays certain markers based on a radius around your current location. The radius is between 100 - 5000 meters. I change the radius with an `UISlider` and redraw the `GMSCircle`.

My problem is that I want to update the camera zoom according to the slider value but I don't have an idea by which scale to divide.

This is how I create the camera in the `viewDidLoad` method where the initial zoom value is 15:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude  zoom:15];
```

Here's a screenshot of what I am working on.

[image]

Does anyone know what scale should I use to move the zoom accordingly?

Thanks a lot!

Granit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the help of Saxon Druce,finally I did it.

```
class MapUtil {

class func translateCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, metersLat: Double,metersLong: Double) -> (CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    var tempCoord = coordinate

    let tempRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, metersLat, metersLong)
    let tempSpan = tempRegion.span

    tempCoord.latitude = coordinate.latitude + tempSpan.latitudeDelta
    tempCoord.longitude = coordinate.longitude + tempSpan.longitudeDelta

    return tempCoord
}

class func setRadius(radius: Double,withCity city: CLLocationCoordinate2D,InMapView mapView: GMSMapView) {

    let range = MapUtil.translateCoordinate(city, metersLat: radius * 2, metersLong: radius * 2)

    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: city, coordinate: range)

    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 5.0)    // padding set to 5.0

    mapView.moveCamera(update)

    // location
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: city)
    marker.title = "title"
    marker.snippet = "snippet"
    marker.flat = true
    marker.map = mapView

    // draw circle
    let circle = GMSCircle(position: city, radius: radius)
    circle.map = mapView
    circle.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.6, blue:0.41, alpha:0.5)

    mapView.animateToLocation(city) // animate to center
}
```

}[image]

Answer (score 32):

Here's a simpler solution for getting the bounds of a `GMSCircle`.
It doesn't rely on MapKit and avoids the two calls that change the camera position (`moveCamera` and `animateToLocation`)

```
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSCircle {
    func bounds () -> GMSCoordinateBounds {
        func locationMinMax(_ positive : Bool) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            let sign: Double = positive ? 1 : -1
            let dx = sign * self.radius  / 6378000 * (180 / .pi)
            let lat = position.latitude + dx
            let lon = position.longitude + dx / cos(position.latitude * .pi / 180)
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        }

        return GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: locationMinMax(true),
                               coordinate: locationMinMax(false))
    }
}
```

After adding this file to your project, all you have to do is:

```
let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(myCircle.bounds())
myMap.animate(with: update)
```

where `myCircle` and `myMap` are replaced by the actual circle and map.

Comment: Works great! :)

Comment: thnks alot buddy :-)

Comment: @Vlad Lego can you clarify why you have used 6378000 constant?

Comment: @Vignesh 6378000 is the "Radius of circle with string around Earth in meters".

Comment: @Vlad Lego can u give this ans in objective-c?

Comment: How can I Change GMSCircle radius relative to zoom level? I need the circle to be in same radius on zoom.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `fitBounds` method of [`GMSCameraUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_update), passing in a `GMSCoordinateBounds` which is calculated from the edges of your circle.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635926/148241), it looks like you could use `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` to convert your centre (lat/lon) plus radius (metres) into a `MKCoordinateRegion`, which will convert the metres into a span in degrees, therefore allowing you to calculate the coordinates in degrees which you'd use to create the `GMSCoordinateBounds`.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3

```
extension GMSCircle {
var bounds: GMSCoordinateBounds {
    return [0, 90, 180, 270].map {
        GMSGeometryOffset(position, radius, $0)
        }.reduce(GMSCoordinateBounds()) {
            $0.includingCoordinate($1)
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
mapView.animate(with: .fit(circle.bounds))
```

Comment: Way simpler, this should be the accepted answer!
Good to mention that you can add a `withPadding` parameter on the `.fit` to change the padding. The default is 64, changed mine to 16.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I just created extension for GMSCameraUpdate.

**input parameters:**

**coordinate** - your center coordinate

**radius** - radius of visible bounds

```
extension GMSCameraUpdate {

    static func fit(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double) -> GMSCameraUpdate {
        var leftCoordinate = coordinate
        var rigthCoordinate = coordinate

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, radius, radius)
        let span = region.span

        leftCoordinate.latitude = coordinate.latitude - span.latitudeDelta
        leftCoordinate.longitude = coordinate.longitude - span.longitudeDelta
        rigthCoordinate.latitude = coordinate.latitude + span.latitudeDelta
        rigthCoordinate.longitude = coordinate.longitude + span.longitudeDelta

        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: leftCoordinate, coordinate: rigthCoordinate)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: -15.0)

        return update
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

hope it will work.

in view controller initialise this circle

```
 var cirlce: GMSCircle!
```

in viewdidload

```
 cirlce = GMSCircle(position: camera.target, radius: 10000)
        cirlce.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
               cirlce.map = mapView
```

call the delegate of googlemap

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
           print(position.zoom)
        var zoom:Double = Double(position.zoom/4)
        zoom = pow(10, zoom)
        zoom = 1000000/zoom
         cirlce.radius = zoom
    }
```