# How to fit bounds of GMSCircle with google maps SDK to completely show on map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to show completely `GMSCircle` on MapView but `radius` of circle is dynamically changed. 
When `radius` is changed then `MapView` will be automatically adjust to view the complete circle on map to show all marker.

In `Swift` language, I have found a solution which may be helpful for me as given here: [Change Camera Zoom based on Radius Google Maps iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115047/change-camera-zoom-based-on-radius-google-maps-ios-sdk)

But I have to implement this in `Objective-c` and in `Objective-c` we didn't have bound property for `GMSCircle`.

Thanks in Advance,Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set zoom level according to your radius

```
 // SET ZOOM LEVEL
    int zoomLevel = 11;
    double radius = raduismeter+ raduismeter / 2;
    double scale = radius / 500;
    zoomLevel = (int) (16 - log(scale) / log(2));
    zoomLevel++;
```

you have to set and calculate zoom level according to your need. Than you have to set radius circle

```
  GMSCircle *geoFenceCircle = [[GMSCircle alloc] init];
            geoFenceCircle.position =PinDropCoordinates;
            geoFenceCircle.strokeWidth = 0.5;
            geoFenceCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];        
            NSLog(@"%@",geoFenceCircle);
            geoFenceCircle.radius =5000.00;
            geoFenceCircle.map = self.mapView;
```

After setting circle  you have to animate your Camera accordingly.

```
    [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:PinDropCoordinates.latitude
                                                                longitude:PinDropCoordinates.longitude zoom:zoomLevel];
        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition: camera];


        [CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It's helpful for me with some minor changes.